No implicit conversion Error while extracting nested parameter in Rails self method
I am trying to implement search functionality based on parameters by passing into rails model self method. While checking passed parameter conditionally on query I am getting no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer.
my article.rb file like the following
 class Article < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 100 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 300 }

  def self.search_artcat(params)
     @articles = Article.where(title: params[:article][:title]) if params[:article][:title].present?
  end 

end

I am accessing title and description from article parameter.
Screenshot

Can anyone guide me to resolve this error in my query ?

Look at the incoming parameters in the terminal or log. params[:acticle] is most likely a string and not a nested instance of ActionController::Parameters. Also even if you fix that you'll still get a NoMethodError if params[:acticle] is nil. Use #dig to safely traverse the params (params.dig(:article, :title)), the nil object pattern (search_params = params.fetch(:article, {})) .

Try to do this params[:article, :title]

Thank you for your response. I tried this. But still erroring out with same message.
